# EXECUTE AS USER in Synapse Serverless: Anyone got it working for a AD/AAD login?

Tags: azure-synapse

SQLServer based logins seem to work the same On Prem and in Synapse Serverless

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'SQLLoginName'
```

Both work fine.

However, for a user whose access is based on membership in an AD/AAD Group, it does not

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'xyz\john.smith'
```

The above works in On-Prem SQL Server, but in Synapse Serverless gives an error

"Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'xyz\john.smith', error code 0x534."

Checking documentation:

"Although CompanyDomain\SqlUser1 has access to the database through membership in the SQLUsers group, the statement EXECUTE AS USER = 'CompanyDomain\SqlUser1' fails because CompanyDomain\SqlUser1 does not exist as a principal in the database."

OK then how can I get this to work?  [Datawarehouse - Restricted Users] exists in both sys.database_principals & sys.server_principals

I tried running EXECUTE AS USER

- Dropping the domain:  EXECUTE AS 'john.smith''
- Using the full email: EXECUTE AS  'john.smith@mycompany.com'
- Using the name of the user/security group: EXECUTE AS  [Datawarehouse - Restricted Users]
- Dropping the domain from the front: EXECUTE AS 'john.smith'
- Testing with an AAD (instead of AD) group as the base of the login.

I am the Synapse Administrator for the Synapse Workspace.

Clearly I'm throwing stuff at the wall to see if anything sticks for EXECUTE AS USER. (Per the documentation - 'EXECUTE AS LOGIN' isn't available in Synapse, so that one is out.)

Just in case it matters, this is how I'd setup everything:

```
use master
GO
CREATE LOGIN [Datawarehouse - Restricted Users]  FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

use DataWareHouseServerless
GO
CREATE USER [Datawarehouse - Restricted Users] FROM LOGIN   [Datawarehouse - Restricted Users]

use DataWareHouseServerless
GO
CREATE ROLE ReadOnlyRestricted

use DataWareHouseServerless
ALTER ROLE ReadOnlyRestricted ADD MEMBER  [Datawarehouse - Restricted Users]
```

Comment: Impersonate permissions are also required as per the docs.  Can’t see that in your code?

Comment: Good point.  In the Synapse Workspace, I'm the Synapse Administrator - so that should cover it, shouldn't it?

Comment: I tried the same may be for AD group it is not supported but when I tried to use it with the single AD user It is working fine.

Comment: @PratikLad Just to confirm, how did you format the single AD user 'email@company.com' or?

Comment: Yes in the same way when I created user for single AD user and then if I try to use execute as user query it's working for me.